# How to change the class of a H element in Wagtail Draftail Editor

Tags: django, wagtail

I would like to add custom classes to H1, H2, H3, etc. in the Draftail editor.

I was looking at hooks but I am unsure if I'm looking at the right method, if you get what I mean?

The result I would like to have is, for example:

```
<h1 class="custom-h2"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </h1>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should provide what you need:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html.  Also a good video here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4M0MEtE_H0.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a `RichTextField()` you can give it `features` to enable or disable Draftail settings.

```
class YourPage(Page):

    ...
    custom_model_field = RichTextField(features=["h1", "h2", "h3", "bold", "italic"])
```

You can do the same with the `RichTextBlock` in a streamfield like so:

```
class CustomStreamfield(blocks.StructBlock):

    ...
    content = RichTextBlock(features=["h1", "h2", "bold", "italic"])
```